# Bind string observer collection to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can find same question from here. I tried all the ways. But none of them did not fix my issue. So please don't mark this as duplicated.

This is what I am trying to do. I have an string list and I want to bind list items to the combobox.

Can please anybody help me to find what is the wrong I am doing on here.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}" DataContext="{Binding AvailableTypes}"/>
```

**.cs File**

```
    ObservableCollection<string> availableTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> AvailableTypes { get { return availableTypes ; } }

    public Window1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        availablePayTypes.Add("Type1");  
        availablePayTypes.Add("Type1");           
    }
```

Data does not get bind to the combobox. If I do as follows it works.

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource=AvailableTypes;
```

What is the wrong with my code. Please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two things wrong.  First, you have a typo -- `ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePayTypes}"` should be `AvailableTypes` to match the property name.

Second, you don't need to set both the `DataContext` and the `ItemsSource`.  Normally you'd set the `DataContext` of the XAML root to be your code-behind class, and then use `ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}"`.

Note that you can set the DataContext either from code-behind:

```
public Window1()
{            
    InitializeComponent();
    availablePayTypes.Add("Type1");  
    availablePayTypes.Add("Type1");           
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

Or from the XAML itself using `RelativeSource`:

```
<UserControl
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Actually there was copy and paste mistake on my code.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of DataContext and ItemsSource binding is incorrect.

This will work:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}" />
```

And in your constructor:

```
public Window1()
{            
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; // <--
    availablePayTypes.Add("Type1");  
    availablePayTypes.Add("Type1");           
}
```

What is going on here?

1. You bound to `AvailablePayTypes` while the collection is named `AvailableTypes`.
2. You are binding the DataContext to `AvailablePayTypes`. But this doesn't work, because your Window itself has no DataContext set, so WPF doesn't know where to look for `AvailablePayTypes`.
3. You are binding the ItemsSource to `AvailablePayTypes`. Even if the previous binding of the DataContext would work, WPF would now look for a property named `AvailablePayTypes` on the collection `AvailablePayTypes`. This is obviously wrong.

I made the following changes to your code:

1. Fixed typo
2. Removed the binding of the DataContext of the ComboBox, so that it gets inherited from the Window
3. In the constructor of the Window, I set the DataContext to itself.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Actually there was copy and paste mistake on my code.Anyway thank you for the the guidance.